# CSS: How to shrink td containing ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have done quite a bit or searching on this but could not find a solution for my specific case. I am a beginner to CSS and the solution is probably really simple, I just cannot find it. So I am trying to create a table that has some columns with long text. I am able to show ellipsis to cut off too long text, but I would like to have the column resize and the ellipsis be updated if I reduce the size of the window, that also reduces the size of the table itself. Now the cell width remains the same and a horizontal scroll bar is shown, which I want to prevent. I know using fixed width for the column is probably the problem, but it is the only way I am able to show the ellipsis in the first place, without fixed width no ellipsis is shown. Here is a very simplified piece of code and the css that easily shows the problem:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          first column
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="overflowTableText">
            the entire text that is way too long to show all at once
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
.tableFixHead {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.overflowTableText {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: Do you have just 2 columns in the table?

Comment: no, this is just a simple example to show the actual issue. The table has 6 columns, 2 of them containing a div of class overflowTableText. I want them both to shrink in size simultaneously when the table gets too small, but only shrinking one would be fine as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit I found a solution that works with multiple columns with ellipsis:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>one</th>
      <th>two</th>
      <th>three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100px">
        first column
      </td>
      <td class="overflowTableText"><span>
        the entire text that is way too long to show all at once the entire text that is way too long to show all at once</span>
      </td>
      <td class="overflowTableText"><span>
        the entire text that is way too long to show all at once the entire text that is way too long to show all at once</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```
.tableFixHead {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 90%;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.overflowTableText {
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `@media` query. Do something like this

```css
.tableFixHead {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.overflowTableText {
    max-width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* add as many break points you want */
@media screen (max-width: 768px) {
    .overflowTableText {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
}
@media screen (max-width: 576px) {
    .overflowTableText {
        max-width: 150px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>one</th>
                <th>two</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>first column</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="overflowTableText">
                        the entire text that is way too long to show all at once
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that out in codepen, but it does not work. Besides I do not want it to set it to a specific width once a certain screen width is reached, I want it to dynamically change with every change in the screen width, like it being sized relatively to the table's width.

Answer (score -1):

Good day, Do you know bootstap? you can easily do that with bootsrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a look at bootstrap, however I did not find any section there that does what I am looking for. I guess what I am looking for is for the div and the td to be dynamically shrunk if the table itself shrinks due to a screen resize. Usually this works but once I add the  nowrap and overflow it fixes the column width to a certain size